# WinHTTP Error Invalid URL

Tags: c++, winhttp

How do you specify a URL with path for example: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions`.

The following works but not with the URL specified above in example.

```
 LPCWSTR useragent = L"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 GTB7.1 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
 DWORD dwSize = 0;
 DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
 LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
 BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
 HINTERNET  hSession = NULL, hConnect = NULL, hRequest = NULL;

 // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
 hSession = WinHttpOpen(useragent,  
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, 
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0 );

 // Specify an HTTP server.
 if( hSession )
  hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, L"www.stackoverflow.com",
          INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0 );

 // Create an HTTP request handle.
 if( hConnect )
 hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET", NULL, NULL,WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
       WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 
      WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE );

 // Send a request.
  if( hRequest ) bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0 );

 // End the request.
 if( bResults )
 bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WinHttpConnect` takes only the hostname part. You should pass the rest of the path to [`WinHttpOpenRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (the third parameter, `pwszObjectName`):

```
WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET", L"/questions", NULL,WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
       WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 
      WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE );
```